# OpenCL device only visible as root

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, linux, opencl

I'm trying to enable gpu rendering on my Vega 64 card in linux, but I can only do so as root. When I run blender as root user, this is what I see in preferences:

[image]

The first one will cause my whole computer to freeze if I try rendering with it, but the second one works fine, albeit slow.

All I see as a normal user is the option that freezes my system:

[image]

Is there some trick to show both devices as normal user?

Some of my system specs. I'm running Gentoo with kernel 4.19.0 using the open source AMDGPU driver. I've install [ROCm](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm) from their github repos for OpenCL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution was to change the ownership of /dev/kfd from root:root to root:video. Then add it to a udev rule to make it persistant:

Add this to /etc/udev/rules.d/60-kfd-opencl.rules

`KERNEL=="kfd", MODE="0660", GROUP="video"`